# Exception in accessing AX method through web Service (Application Integration Framework) in Ax 2012

Tags: web-services, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

[image: Exception in accessing AX method]

Here “retrieveCustomerIds” is my AX method which I am trying to access from webservice.

Definition of retrieveCustomerIds

```
[AifCollectionTypeAttribute('return', Types::String), SysEntryPointAttribute(False)]

public List retrieveCustomerIds()
{
List resultSet = new List(Types::String);

CustTable   custTable;
while select custTable

{
    resultSet.addEnd(custTable.AccountNum);
}

return resultSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got success by changing the SPN to blank in my application config file.